# VM Exception while processing transaction: revert at PromiEvent

Tags: solidity, erc-20, truffle-console

I have a problem when calling smart contract function using truffle console. Previously I deployed smart contracts on ropsten, and there was no problem when calling smart contract function. Anyone know the problem? Thanks.

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.21 <0.7.0;

import "./StandardToken.sol";
import "./Owned.sol";

contract Konserta is StandardToken, Owned {
    string public name; 
    string public symbol;    
    uint256 public tokenprice; 
    string public version = "v0.1";
    uint8 public constant decimals = 8; 
    uint256 public constant INITIAL_SUPPLY = 700 * (10 ** uint256(decimals));

    constructor() public  {
        name = "Token 1";                     
        totSupply = INITIAL_SUPPLY;
        balances[msg.sender] = INITIAL_SUPPLY;         
        emit Transfer(address(0),msg.sender,INITIAL_SUPPLY);
        symbol = "TKN"; 
    }

    function getBalanceContract() view public returns(uint256) {
        return address(this).balance;
    }
}
```

Contract successfully deployed but when I call getBalanceContract() function, the result is

```
truffle(development)> let instance = await Konserta.at("0xC657b719f2806bcAf98ab3374BE51e7822746E65")    
truffle(development)> instance.getBalanceContract()
    Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert at PromiEvent (/Users/myuser/.nvm/versions/node/v8.10.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/contract/lib/promievent.js:9:1)
        at TruffleContract.getBalanceContract (/Users/myuser/.nvm/versions/node/v8.10.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/contract/lib/execute.js:120:1)
        at evalmachine.<anonymous>:0:10
        at sigintHandlersWrap (vm.js:98:15)
        at ContextifyScript.Script.runInContext (vm.js:56:12)
        at runScript (/Users/myuser/.nvm/versions/node/v8.10.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/console.js:222:1)
        at Console.interpret (/Users/myuser/.nvm/versions/node/v8.10.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/console.js:237:1)
        at ReplManager.interpret (/Users/myuser/.nvm/versions/node/v8.10.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/repl.js:131:1)
        at bound (domain.js:301:14)
        at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:314:12)
        at REPLServer.onLine (repl.js:468:10)
        at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
        at REPLServer.emit (events.js:211:7)
        at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (readline.js:282:10)
        at REPLServer.Interface._line (readline.js:631:8)
        at REPLServer.Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:911:14)
        at REPLServer.self._ttyWrite (repl.js:537:7)
        at ReadStream.onkeypress (readline.js:160:10)
        at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
        at ReadStream.emit (events.js:214:7)
        at emitKeys (internal/readline.js:420:14)
        at emitKeys.next (<anonymous>)
```

Comment: Are you sure the contract was deployed correctly? There is no contract at that address in ropsten.

Comment: I deploy in local network, not in ropsten. I mean I ever deploy different contract  in ropsten and there was no problem when calling function.

Comment: Are you using ganache or another type of private testnet? In case you run a private testnet did you enable  newer opcodes in genesis file?

Comment: Yes, I use ganache and i have enabled that.